# Преобразование из С++ в С

Tags: c++, c

Вот это часть когда написана в С++, как она будет выглядеть в С

```
  cout «setw(6) «a[i][j];
    cout «setw(6) «setprecision(2) «a[i][j];
```

Весь код:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iomanip> 
//using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
srand (time(NULL)); 
const int M = 4; 
const int N = 7; 
float a[M][N]; 
for (int i=0; i<M; i++) 
{ 
for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
{ 
a[i][j]=rand()%10+1; 
printf("%d ", (a[i][j])); 
//cout «setw(6) «a[i][j]; 
} 
//cout «endl; 
} 
float max[M]={0.0F}; 
for (int i=0; i<M; i++) 
{ 
max[i] = a[i][0]; 
for (int j=1; j<N; j++) 
if (a[i][j] > max[i]) 
max[i] = a[i][j]; 
} 
cout «endl; 
for (int i=0; i<M; i++) 
{ 
for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
{ 
a[i][j]/=max[i]; 
cout «setw(6) «setprecision(2) «a[i][j]; 
} 
cout «endl; 
} 
system("pause"); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Како1 тип элементов у массива a?

Comment: const int M = 4; 
const int N = 7; 
float a[M][N];

Comment: Никак. Что за символ `«` и что он делает в С++ коде?

Comment: @Valera  Да, как-то, весь помещенный код не добавляет к вопросу новой информации. Вы можете его удалить, тем более, что он содержит синтаксически не допустимые символы.:)

Comment: @Valera  Помимо некорректных символов, у вас в коде имеются и другие ошибки. Например, в этом предложении  printf("%d ", (a[i][j])); используется неправильный формат вывода, а потому поведение функции неопределенное.

Comment: @Valera  Вы можете задать новый, еще один  вопрос, касающийся проблем с компиляцией вашего кода.

Comment: @AnT это обычно возникает из-за автоформатирования в каком-нибудь MSWord.

Answer (score 2):

Если запустить следующую демонстрационную программу, написанную на C++, которая содержит предложения вывода, указанные в вашем вопросе (я считаю, что типографская открывающаяся двойная кавычка `«`  - это опечатка и вместо нее должен присутствовать оператор `<<`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    float a[1][1] = { { 123.456789 } };
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    std::cout << std::setw( 6 ) << a[i][j] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw( 6 ) << std::setprecision( 2 ) << a[i][j] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

То ее вывод на консоль будет следующим

```
123.457
1.2e+02
```

Аналогичный вывод можно получить, запустив на выполнение следующую демонстрационную программу, написанную на C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float a[1][1] = { { 123.456789 } };
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    printf( "%6g\n", a[i][j] );
    printf( "%6.2g\n", a[i][j] );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
123.457
1.2e+02
```